# Trying to import GitHub module

Tags: python, visual-studio, github

I'm trying to import https://github.com/chrisconlan/algorithmic-trading-with-python in my code. I've never imported anything from GitHub before and have looked at various other questions that have been asked on Stack Overflow regarding this problem but it just doesn't work. When I try to run the 'portfolio.py' code for example I keep getting a ModuleNotFound error for 'pypm'. What exactly is the correct way to import such a module or the whole GitHub directory?
I'm working with Visual Studio Code on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pip install the module. In your case the command you would need to run is `python -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/chrisconlan/algorithmic-trading-with-python`. Once you have done that you need to find the name of the module. You can do this with `pip list`. Find the name of the module you just installed.
Then you just stick `import <module name>` at the top of your code with the rest of your imports.

Answer (score -1):

What i used to do in this is to clone the repository on the folder where are installed the python's packages. This is useful when you do not want to use the pip cmd tool, keeping the pip's cache memory under control.